# How to extract JSON field using Jsoup and Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, jsoup

In my program, I connect to a URL to retrieve the `json` using `Jsoup`.

Here is the method for to retrieve the `json` [having the `subject = example`]:

```
private void result() throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    List<String> list = newsList.getSelectedValuesList();
    for (String s : list) {
       Annotation doc = new Annotation(s);
       pipeline.annotate(doc); 
       for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
            Collection<RelationTriple> triples =
         sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
            // Print the triples
            for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
                /* replace space with "_" */
                String subject = triple.subjectLemmaGloss().replace(" ", "_");
                String object = triple.objectGloss().replace(" ", "_");
                String kb = "http://api.conceptnet.io/c/en/" + subject;
                Document docKb = Jsoup.connect(kb).get();
                String json = docKb.body().text();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Map<String, Object> asMap = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), Map.class);
                List<Map<String, Object>> edges = (List) asMap.get("edges");
                for (Map<String, Object> edge : edges) {
                    if (edge.containsKey("surfaceText") && edge.containsKey("weight")) {
                       txtAreaNews.append(edge.get("surfaceText").toString() + "\n"); 
                       txtAreaNews.append("Weight: " + edge.get("weight").toString());
                    }
                    txtAreaNews.append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `html` that I retrieved from the URL at `txtAreaNews.append(docKb.text());`:

```
 ConceptNet 5 API {
  "@context": [
    "http://api.conceptnet.io/ld/conceptnet5.5/context.ld.json",
    "http://api.conceptnet.io/ld/conceptnet5.5/pagination.ld.json"
  ],
  "@id": "/c/en/example",
  "edges": [
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/apology/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/apology/n",
        "label": "apology",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/apology"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[apology]] is a type of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/example/n/,/c/en/admonition/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/admonition/n",
        "label": "admonition",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/admonition"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[example]] is a type of [[admonition]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/example/n/,/c/en/information/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/information/n",
        "label": "information",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/information"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[example]] is a type of [[information]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/exception/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/exception/n",
        "label": "exception",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/exception"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[exception]] is a type of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/precedent/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/precedent/n",
        "label": "precedent",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/precedent"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[precedent]] is a type of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/quintessence/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/quintessence/n",
        "label": "quintessence",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/quintessence"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[quintessence]] is a type of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/sample/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/sample/n",
        "label": "sample",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/sample"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[sample]] is a type of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/IsA/,/c/en/specimen/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/IsA",
        "label": "IsA"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/specimen/n",
        "label": "specimen",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/specimen"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[specimen]] is a type of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/exemplary/a/,/c/en/example/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wiktionary/en",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by-sa/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/RelatedTo",
        "label": "RelatedTo"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/and/[/s/process/wikiparsec/1/,/s/resource/wiktionary/en/]",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wiktionary/en",
          "process": "/s/process/wikiparsec/1"
        },
        {
          "@id": "/and/[/s/process/wikiparsec/1/,/s/resource/wiktionary/fr/]",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wiktionary/fr",
          "process": "/s/process/wikiparsec/1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/exemplary/a",
        "label": "exemplary",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "a",
        "term": "/c/en/exemplary"
      },
      "surfaceText": null,
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/exemplify/v/,/c/en/example/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wiktionary/en",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by-sa/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/RelatedTo",
        "label": "RelatedTo"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/and/[/s/process/wikiparsec/1/,/s/resource/wiktionary/en/]",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wiktionary/en",
          "process": "/s/process/wikiparsec/1"
        },
        {
          "@id": "/and/[/s/process/wikiparsec/1/,/s/resource/wiktionary/fr/]",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wiktionary/fr",
          "process": "/s/process/wikiparsec/1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/exemplify/v",
        "label": "exemplify",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "v",
        "term": "/c/en/exemplify"
      },
      "surfaceText": null,
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/ar/مِثَال/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/ar/مِثَال/n",
        "label": "مِثَال",
        "language": "ar",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/ar/مِثَال"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[مِثَال]] is a translation of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/ar/مَثَل/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/ar/مَثَل/n",
        "label": "مَثَل",
        "language": "ar",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/ar/مَثَل"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[مَثَل]] is a translation of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/ca/escarment/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/ca/escarment/n",
        "label": "escarment",
        "language": "ca",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/ca/escarment"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[escarment]] is a translation of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/ca/exemple/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/ca/exemple/n",
        "label": "exemple",
        "language": "ca",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/ca/exemple"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[exemple]] is a translation of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/ca/lliçó/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/ca/lliçó/n",
        "label": "lliçó",
        "language": "ca",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/ca/lliçó"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[lliçó]] is a translation of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/da/eksempel/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/da/eksempel/n",
        "label": "eksempel",
        "language": "da",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/da/eksempel"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[eksempel]] is a translation of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/en/deterrent_example/n/,/c/en/example/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/deterrent_example/n",
        "label": "deterrent example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/deterrent_example"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[deterrent example]] is a synonym of [[example]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/en/example/n/,/c/en/case/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/case/n",
        "label": "case",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/case"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[example]] is a synonym of [[case]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/en/example/n/,/c/en/exemplar/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/exemplar/n",
        "label": "exemplar",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/exemplar"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[example]] is a synonym of [[exemplar]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    },
    {
      "@id": "/a/[/r/Synonym/,/c/en/example/n/,/c/en/exercise/n/]",
      "dataset": "/d/wordnet/3.1",
      "end": {
        "@id": "/c/en/exercise/n",
        "label": "exercise",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/exercise"
      },
      "license": "cc:by/4.0",
      "rel": {
        "@id": "/r/Synonym",
        "label": "Synonym"
      },
      "sources": [
        {
          "@id": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1",
          "contributor": "/s/resource/wordnet/rdf/3.1"
        }
      ],
      "start": {
        "@id": "/c/en/example/n",
        "label": "example",
        "language": "en",
        "sense_label": "n",
        "term": "/c/en/example"
      },
      "surfaceText": "[[example]] is a synonym of [[exercise]]",
      "weight": 2.0
    }
  ],
  "view": {
    "@id": "/c/en/example?offset=0&limit=20",
    "firstPage": "/c/en/example?offset=0&limit=20",
    "nextPage": "/c/en/example?offset=20&limit=20",
    "paginatedProperty": "edges"
  }
}
```

Example of `surfaceText` that are null:

```
{
   "@id": "/a/[/r/RelatedTo/,/c/en/exemplary/a/,/c/en/example/]",
   "dataset": "/d/wiktionary/en",
   "end": {
     "@id": "/c/en/example",
     "label": "example",
     "language": "en",
     "term": "/c/en/example"
   },
   "license": "cc:by-sa/4.0",
  "rel": {
     "@id": "/r/RelatedTo",
     "label": "RelatedTo"
   },
   "sources": [
     {
       "@id": "/and/[/s/process/wikiparsec/1/,/s/resource/wiktionary/en/]",
       "contributor": "/s/resource/wiktionary/en",
       "process": "/s/process/wikiparsec/1"
     },
     {
       "@id": "/and/[/s/process/wikiparsec/1/,/s/resource/wiktionary/fr/]",
       "contributor": "/s/resource/wiktionary/fr",
       "process": "/s/process/wikiparsec/1"
     }
   ],
   "start": {
     "@id": "/c/en/exemplary/a",
     "label": "exemplary",
     "language": "en",
     "sense_label": "a",
     "term": "/c/en/exemplary"
   },
   "surfaceText": null,
   "weight": 2.0
}
```

I would like to ask, how can I get `"surfaceText"` and `"weight"` from the above rerieved data with Jsoup or Gson?

Comment: do you want to use only jsoup/ Gson?

Comment: @VedX it would be nice if jsoup can do it. But jsoup is a HTML parser. So i am not sure if it is possible to only use jsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialise the JSON into a `Map` and then interrogate the `Map`.

Here's an example:

```
String kb = "http://api.conceptnet.io/c/en/example";
Document docKb = Jsoup.connect(kb).get();
String json = docKb.body().text();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> asMap = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
List<Map<String, Object>> edges = (List) asMap.get("edges");
for (Map<String, Object> edge : edges) {
    // check that the response contains a surfaceText
    if (edge.containsKey("surfaceText")) {
        // check that the surfaceText value is non-null
        String surfaceText = (String) edge.get("surfaceText");
        if (surfaceText != null) {
            System.out.println(edge.get("surfaceText"));
        }
    }
    if (edge.containsKey("weight")) {
        System.out.println(edge.get("weight"));
    }
}
```

This code will print out:

```
[[apology]] is a type of [[example]]
2.0
[[example]] is a type of [[admonition]]
2.0
[[example]] is a type of [[information]]
2.0
[[exception]] is a type of [[example]]
2.0
... etc
```

Comment: I tried this: `String json = docKb.text();` and pass into `gson.fromJson(...)` but I got this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

Comment: Ok, so `docKb.text()` is not returning valid JSON. The `json` that you showed in your question _is_ valid JSON but whatever you are getting back from  `docKb.text()` is _not_ JSON. Perhaps it is just wrapped up in some outer tags? I'd suggest debugging or printing out exactly what that call returns and (a) you'll see that it is not valid JSON and (b) you might be able to see how to extract valid JSON from it.

Comment: `docKb.text()` returns HTML. Am I right to say that I need to convert the returned HTML to JSON and pass into `gson.fromJson(...)`?

Comment: Can you update your question to show a small example of the HTML response?

Comment: I have updated the question with the HTML that I retrieved

Comment: I am able to retrieve the to pass the retrieved `html` to `json`, but when I am getting the `surfaceText` field, if the `"surfaceText": null`, the error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` is shown. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have updated the answer to make the accessors null-safe, see `if (edge.containsKey("surfaceText")){ ...}`

Comment: I have updated the question with code which (1) uses JSoup to read a response from http://api.conceptnet.io/c/en/example; (2) extracts JSON from that response; (3) deserialises that JSON into a Map and reads the  surfaceText and weight attributes from that Map. This code completes succesfully without an NullPointerException. So, the NPE you are getting is not coming from JSoup or Gson invocations, it must be coming from some other aspect of your code. There's really no way for me to know where without a reproduction case i.e. your code and a stacktrace showing which **line** the NPE occurs on.

Comment: There are some surfaceText attributes in the retrieved response is null. Which is showed in the html in the updated question e.g. `"surfaceText": null`. Does it cause the null pointer error?

Comment: the null pointer error occurs at the line `txtAreaNews.append(edge.get("surfaceText").toString() + "\n");`

Comment: I've updated the answer to cater for responses which contain the `surfaceText` key with a null value.